# How to fix clipping when you have multiple clothing in 1 character

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]

As the title already stated, how would you fix this clipping?

I have an underbody suit, a shirt, and the skirt as the topmost layer with everything separated. Everything was imported via .obj from Fuse CC, and I want to use Blender to fix the clipping, so then I could export this to Unity.

Answer (score -1):

I have had this problem as well and I know that when you zoom in it usually goes away.

This problem is fixed when you render the image. When rendering, all the positions of the vertices are calculated correctly. In the viewport, positions of the vertices are estimated to save computing power. Therefore they might not look right.

Comment: There's no other way to fix the mesh? because I want to export this out to Unity

Comment: You may export in safely without any clipping. This clipping is like a post process effect to make it run smoother inside blender viewport (terrible explanation). So everywhere you take it, the correct values are being used, except blender viewport to make things run faster. I'm not sure about unity tho... maybe that game engine uses the same technique to make games run smoother, and in this case you should just optimize your mesh more.